# building & linking dynamic library of a .h (header) file in C on linux platform

Tags: c, linux, dynamic-linking

I have to build a dynamic library of a header file using C on Linux platform.
and use it while building my executable. 
How to build dynamic library of a header file?

Comment: Header files do not become dynamic libraries.

Comment: you can link your library to your program like `gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c -lmysharedlib` but i cant get you how you build library from header file?

Answer (score 0):

We can not make shared library from header file please refer http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html for your reference